# Firebase specific data extraction

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

How to extract a specific data from Firebase database into an object and then how to get the data's from the object.

I tried storing it in an object but produces a null pointer exception and I am unsure how to fix it

Comment: Share some code please or non of us can help you

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start The official Firestore RealTime Database shows you how to do everything,just follow the template.

For example:you should create POJO based on your json written in Realtime Database,you can use this website to create it http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.

You will have something like this:

```
public class User {

public String username;
public String email;

public User() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public User(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

Then follow the steps in the documentary on How to retrieve data!

I think it might help you!